# Как задается рабочее время в Redmine?

Tags: redmine

Подскажите, можно ли в Redmine установить, что рабочий день должен быть 8 часов и контролировать это условие? И как можно просмотреть общую занятость по проекту сотрудника? В какие дни у него есть свободные от задач часы, а в какие уже нет?

Answer (score 0):

Можно поставить плагин "time tracker" - он поможет учитывать затраченное время по проекту. Контролировать условие, что рабочий день должен быть равен 8 часам , на сколько я знаю, можно только написав свой плагин.
Но через тайм трекер мы можем видеть сколько часов в день и на какие задачи по проекту было списано время.

Upd
Есть платный плагин для редмайна "Easy Resource Management"
который позволяет ограничить рабочий день 8 часами.